# Could Congress "bribe" the President to sign a bill by including a presidential pay raise?

Tags: united-states, us-constitution, congress, bribery, us-president

If Congress wanted to pass a law that they expected the President to be reluctant to sign, could they legally "bribe" the President to sign the bill by including a Presidential pay raise in it?

Comment: Bribe is a loaded word.  “Would it be considered a bribe if…” might be a better question.

Comment: @MichaelHall good point, but it's moot because they can't do it anyway without waiting for an election.

Comment: Not true.  They could include it in the bill, it just couldn’t legally go into effect.

Comment: @MichaelHall good point; I'll ask another question asking if it would be a bribe.

Comment: It's worth noting that even though the salary of the position is $400k per year, the President usually has so much social status and power that they could easily have access to economic opportunities worth tens of millions if they cared for it, so bribes would have to be at that order of magnitude AT THE LEAST to be meaningful

Comment: A presidential pay rise would be one of the least efficient and most politically dangerous ways to do it. Subtle regulatory tweaks which "just happen" to improve the president's assets or interests would be more straightforward.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

No.

Article 2, Section 1 of the Constitution states

> The President shall, at stated Times, receive for his Services, a
> Compensation, which shall neither be encreased nor diminished during
> the Period for which he shall have been elected, and he shall not
> receive within that Period any other Emolument from the United States,
> or any of them.

Congress could include an increase to presidential compensation in the bill but it couldn't take effect until the next election.

Comment: "No" may be too simple. Grant authorized a presidential pay raise which he benefited from in his second term. (I know nothing about the circumstances surrounding the bill, only that the ability exists for the president to benefit from such a bill.)

Comment: @chepner Your suggestion doesn't work if the president is already in his second term. And a second term is not guaranteed, look at the first Bush or Carter.

Comment: @doneal24 I'm aware of that. (I'm also aware that the optics of signing something *because* it includes a potential raise for yourself could be why you don't get re-elected.) But the question is can Congress *try* this, and could the President "accept" the bribe.

Comment: @chepner - It seems tough to characterize a pay increase that happens after an election takes place as a bribe.  That seems sufficiently speculative and sufficiently removed in time to not be a bribe.  I suppose there could be a loophole where a first term president is currently running for re-election, polling shows him or her to be in a commanding lead and all but certain to win re-election, and Congress passes such a bill.

Comment: @chepner You might also take into consideration the net worth of recent presidents. The poorest ones in recent history, Ford and Carter, still have $9m in assets. Bush and Obama are in the $40m+ range. How big of a pay raise is necessary to make it worth their while?

Comment: Could they agree to pay the President after the election term ended?

Comment: @user253751 - That would almost certainly be ruled an "Emolument from the United States"

Comment: @JustinCave during the period for which he shall have been elected?

Comment: @user253751 - A bill saying "Congress awards the current President a $10 million one-time payment payable the day after the next Presidential election" would almost certainly be considered an emolument that was effective when the bill was signed not when the emolument was payable (and thus awarded during the period for which the President was elected).

Comment: What about for a president that has been re-elected, in the period between the election and when their second term officially starts?

Comment: @GavinS.Yancey - That would appear to be "during the Period for which he shall have been elected".

Comment: Could the president sign the bill late on election day, so the electorate will not have time to hear about it before casting their vote, but still before the counting of the votes begins?

Comment: The time period of most concern is probably between Election Day and when the Electoral College votes.... the president has not yet been officially elected, because the Electoral College does tat, but it's known with extremely high certainty how the EC will vote.

Comment: In theory, there would also be the possibility to amend the constitution. But if something already has such broad support, the president is unlikely to be reluctant for long, if at all. If he is too stubborn, he is more likely to get impeached.